# Elasticsearch - Fuzzy search not giving suggestions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to implement a fuzzy/autocomplete search in Elasticsearch through NodeJS. I have indexed data by index `"artist"`. Here is an example of stored data in ES.

```
{
  "hits": [{
    "_index": "artist",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "EyejqnAB2pHGVJHwV53Q",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "kind": "song",
      "artistId": 111051,
      "artistName": "Eminem",
      "trackName": "Crack a Bottle (feat. Dr. Dre & 50 Cent)",
      "collectionName": "Relapse (Deluxe Version)",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Relapse (Deluxe Version)",
      "artistViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/eminem/111051?uo=4",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/crack-a-bottle-feat-dr-dre-50-cent-feat-dr-dre-50-cent/1440558626?i=1440558826&uo=4",
      "trackViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/crack-a-bottle-feat-dr-dre-50-cent-feat-dr-dre-50-cent/1440558626?i=1440558826&uo=4",
      "previewUrl": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview128/v4/da/a5/c1/daa5c140-2c3d-1f74-40c3-b6e596e52b82/mzaf_7480202713407880256.plus.aac.p.m4a",
      "artworkUrl100": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music128/v4/c5/f8/fd/c5f8fdf6-d4c9-85c9-d169-c5d349a44f1c/source/100x100bb.jpg",
      "collectionPrice": 12.99,
      "releaseDate": "2009-02-02T12:00:00Z",
      "collectionExplicitness": "explicit",
      "trackExplicitness": "explicit",
      "discCount": 1,
      "discNumber": 1,
      "trackCount": 24,
      "trackNumber": 18,
      "country": "USA",
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }]
}
```

Above `artistName` has value as `Eminem` and problem is when I type `'e'`, it doesn't shows anything, same on `'em'`, `emi`, `emin`. When i type `emine` then it starts giving out results. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through the answer and try out the approach I suggested?

Comment: if u want to return results since the first character u could use simplequerystring appending * at the tail of the input string. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

Comment: @JordiJordi, this would lead to wildcard queries, which are very expensive, the same thing can be achieved even using my `prefix` query approach, but I discouraged as with just 1 character, you don't get quality results and its very expensive ones, Pleasr refer to blog in my answer, which explains these trade-off in greater details

Comment: @opster-elasticsearch-ninja i agree, it's better with prefix query

Comment: @JordiJordi, cool  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement the autocomplete functionality, and a fuzzy search is not the correct one(It's mainly used to search the related documents w.r.t to tokens(de-dupe) and in spell-checker refer [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-for-fuzzy-string-matching-with-python-6632b7824c49) for applications of fuzzy search).

In your case, I would suggest **using the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) if your index size isn't huge and restrict the minimum character length to two**, i.e., don't search for `e` and shows search results only when the user typed two or more characters ie `em` or `emi`,`emin` etc.

### Working example

Index mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "artistName": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index doc

```
{
   "artistName" : "Eminem"
}

{
   "artistName" : "Emiten"
}
```

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "artistName": {
                "value": "em"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
{
            "_index": "so-60558525-auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "artistName": "Eminem"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60558525-auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "artistName": "Emiten"
            }
         }
```

### Important read

There are **broadly four approaches that you can choose to implement the autocomplete**, and each of them has some trade-off, which you should be aware of justifying your functional requirement as well as non-functional(performance, maintenance, implementation difficulties).

Answer (score 0):

[Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) returns documents that match a provided text, number, date or boolean value. The provided text is analyzed before matching.
ex  text :"this is a test" with standard analyzer is stored as ["this","is", "a", "token"]
Text you are searching on will also be broken into tokens and these tokens will be matched.

Fuzziness: takes a single term and finds all terms in the dictionary that are within the specified fuzziness. The default fuzziness is AUTO.

Below are values for auto
AUTO -- It generates an edit distance based on the length of the term. For lengths:
0..2 -- must match exactly
3..5 -- one edit allowed

> 5 -- two edits allowed

So you are able to search for "emine" as edit distance is 1

To implement auto completion, you can use
1. EdgeNgrams
2. Completion Suggester

Links to refer for above
1. [AutoCompletion](https://hackernoon.com/elasticsearch-building-autocomplete-functionality-494fcf81a7cf)
2. [Fuzziness](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-optimization-fuzziness-performance)

Comment: completion suggester is still in development, not trivial to implement, aprat from 2 approaches you listed, there are several other approaches to implement autocomplete and one of them, just released `search-as-you-type` data-type in 7.2 version, also users should know the trade-off of all the four approaches to avoid surpirises later on. Please refer my answer for more details

Comment: btw, I published a detailed blog on all four approaches https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/ , please go through it for a deep understanding of autocomplete esp in huge and scalable systems and ping me if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks :), btw not sure, why I am not able to tag you in SO comments :|